# Expected tensorflow model size from learned variables

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, conv-neural-network

When training convolutional neural networks for image classification tasks we generally want our algorithm to learn the filters (and biases) that transform a given image to its correct label. I have a few models I'm trying to compare in terms of model size, number of operations, accuracy, etc. However, the size of the model outputed from tensorflow, concretely the *model.ckpt.data* file that stores the values of all the variables in the graph, is not the one I expected. In fact, it seems to be three times bigger.

To go straight to the problem I'm gonna base my question on [this](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/notebooks/3_NeuralNetworks/convolutional_network_raw.ipynb) Jupyter notebook. Below is the section where the variables (weights and biases) are defined:

```
# Store layers weight & bias
weights = {
# 5x5 conv, 1 input, 32 outputs
'wc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 1, 32]),dtype=tf.float32),
# 5x5 conv, 32 inputs, 64 outputs
'wc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 32, 64]),dtype=tf.float32),
# fully connected, 7*7*64 inputs, 1024 outputs
'wd1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([7*7*64, 1024]),dtype=tf.float32),
# 1024 inputs, 10 outputs (class prediction)
'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024, num_classes]),dtype=tf.float32)
}

biases = {
'bc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32]),dtype=tf.float32),
'bc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64]),dtype=tf.float32),
'bd1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024]),dtype=tf.float32),
'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_classes]),dtype=tf.float32)
}
```

I've added a couple of lines in order to save the model at the end of the training process:

```
# Save the model
save_path = saver.save(sess, logdir+"model.ckpt")
print("Model saved in file: %s" % save_path)
```

Adding up all those variables we would expect to get a *model.ckpt.data* file of size 12.45Mb (I've obtained this by just computing the number of float elements that our model learns and then convert that value to MegaBytes). But! the *.data* file saved is 39.3Mb. Why is this?

I've followed the same approach with a more complex network (a variation of ResNet) and my expected model.data size is also ~3x smaller than what the actual *.data* file is.

The data type of all these variables is float32.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Adding up all those variables we would expect to get a model.ckpt.data file of size 12.45Mb

Traditionally, most of model parameters are in the first fully connected layer, in this case `wd1`. Computing only its size yields:

```
7*7*128 * 1024 * 4 = 25690112
```

... or `25.6Mb`. Note `4` coefficient, because the variable `dtype=tf.float32`, i.e. `4` bytes per parameter. Other layers also contribute to the model size, but not so drastically.

As you can see, your estimate `12.45Mb` is *a bit off* (did you use 16bit per param?). The checkpoint also stores some general information, hence the overhead around 25%, which is still big, but not 300%.

**[Update]**

The model in question actually has FC1 layer of shape `[7*7*64, 1024]`, as was clarified. So the calculated above size should be `12.5Mb`, indeed. That made me look into the saved checkpoint more carefully.

After inspecting it, I noticed other big variables that I missed originally:

```
...
Variable_2 (DT_FLOAT) [3136,1024]
Variable_2/Adam (DT_FLOAT) [3136,1024]
Variable_2/Adam_1 (DT_FLOAT) [3136,1024]
...
```

The `Variable_2` is exactly `wd1`, but there are 2 more copies for the Adam optimizer. These variables are created by [the Adam optimizer](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/adam.py#L118), they're called *slots* and hold the `m` and `v` accumulators **for all trainable variables**. Now the total size makes sense.

You can run the following code to compute the total size of the graph variables - `37.47Mb`:

```
var_sizes = [np.product(list(map(int, v.shape))) * v.dtype.size
             for v in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES)]
print(sum(var_sizes) / (1024 ** 2), 'MB')
```

So the overhead is actually pretty small. Extra size is due to the optimizer.

Comment: oh! thank you. No, i'm using 32bit but i did "7*7*64*1024*4". My fault.

Comment: I've updated my numbers (see edit 1). I still have the problem described in my question.

Comment: @karl71 are you sure you saved the same model? I've just got 39Mb, as you described originally

Comment: sorry for the confusion. My problem is exactly as I described at the beginning. My fault is that the weights and biases code i added originally didn't match that of the Jupyter notebook (it was from another). So, indeed the .data file size is 39Mb but I was also correct when saying that the expected .data file should be 12.5Mb. (essentially your answer above was using the data I wrongly added in the question body). Sorry for the confussion.

Comment: @karl71. Got it, thanks. I've found the reason for this, see my answer

Comment: Question: why do we need optimizer params during inference? Is it some Adam specific behavior?