# Tensorflow : How to optimize trained model size?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am building a simple TensorFlow model where I am fine-tuning the Elmo model using Tf-Hub module.

I am getting a good result but the problem is when I am saving the model, It's very large where the same time I built the same model in Keras and it's in Kb.

My input data is :

```
import numpy as np
data_points = np.array([['that what is good for the goose'],['some of which'],['demonstrating the adage'],['A series of escapades demonstrating']])
data_labels = np.array([[1,0,0,0,0],[1,0,0,1,1],[1,0,0,0,0],[1,0,0,1,1]])
tf_input    = np.array([sent for m in data_points for sent in m])
```

Here is the Keras model :

```
#dl framework
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
from keras import backend as K
import keras.layers as layers
from keras.engine import Layer
from keras.models import Model, load_model
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping,ModelCheckpoint
import pandas as pd
from keras.engine import Layer


class ElmoEmbeddingLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.dimensions = 1024
        self.trainable=True
        super(ElmoEmbeddingLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.elmo = hub.Module('https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2', trainable=self.trainable,
                               name="{}_module".format(self.name))

        self.trainable_weights += K.tf.trainable_variables(scope="^{}_module/.*".format(self.name))
        super(ElmoEmbeddingLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, x, mask=None):
        result = self.elmo(K.squeeze(K.cast(x, tf.string), axis=1),
                      as_dict=True,
                      signature='default',
                      )['default']
        return result

    def compute_mask(self, inputs, mask=None):
        return K.not_equal(inputs, '--PAD--')

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], self.dimensions)


def build_model(): 
    input_text = layers.Input(shape=(1,), dtype="string")
    embedding = ElmoEmbeddingLayer()(input_text)
    pred = layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax')(embedding)
    model = Model(inputs=[input_text], outputs=pred)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.summary()
    return model


model = build_model()
checkpointer   = ModelCheckpoint('model.hdf5', monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
model.fit(data_points,data_labels, validation_data=(data_points,data_labels),epochs=2,
batch_size= 5 ,callbacks=[checkpointer])
```

After training the model size is 87 kb

I built same model in Tensorflow :

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
import tensorflow_hub as hub



class Elmo_model(object):

    def __init__(self):

        tf.reset_default_graph()

        # placeholders
        sentences             = tf.placeholder(tf.string, (None,), name='sentences')
        self.targets          = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None], name='labels' )
        self.placeholders     = {'sentence': sentences, 'labels': self.targets}



        # elmo model
        module                = hub.Module('https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2', trainable = True)
        embeddings            = module(dict(text=sentences))

        dense_layer           = tf.layers.dense(embeddings, 5)


        #optimization and loss calculation ---------------------------------->>

        self.cross_entropy = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = dense_layer, labels = tf.cast(self.targets,tf.float32))
        self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(self.cross_entropy, axis=1))
        self.optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = 0.001).minimize(self.loss)
        self.predictions = tf.cast(tf.sigmoid(dense_layer) > 0.5, tf.int32)
```

training :

```
def model_execute(model):

    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run([tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.tables_initializer()])

        for iteration in range(5):
            model_out,train = sess.run([model.loss,model.optimizer],feed_dict={model.placeholders['sentence']: tf_input,
                                                                           model.placeholders['labels']: data_labels})
        print(model_out)
        saver.save(sess, 'tf_model.hdf5')



model_out = Elmo_model()
model_execute(model_out)
```

After training for the same epoch and same dataset, the TensorFlow model size is 374.5 MB

My question is How Keras optimize the model and How to save model like Keras in Tensorflow?
I went through this [issue on github](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/149)  and [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47314011/expected-tensorflow-model-size-from-learned-variables) but couldn't find it helpful.

Comment: Do you get the same training results in both case?

Comment: @Geeocode yes, almost same accuracy.

Comment: Actually I can't reproduce the problem, because tensorflow_hub throw the error: 
`RuntimeError: variable_scope elmo_embedding_layer_2_module/ was unused but the corresponding name_scope was already taken.` and it seems it is an unsolved tfhub currently as per github.

Comment: Anyway I can't reproduce, but I think Keras didn't saved the embedded model's parameters, as it seems to me too small with a few kB.

Comment: @Geeocode which tensorflow version you are using ?

Comment: Did you use `model.save` in Keras? I think you saved only the model's configuration without weights, as Aaditya said.

Comment: @DanielMöller  In keras I am using in-built function checkpoint, check the code above.

Comment: I see.... the next guess is that nowhere in your layer you are registering trianable wieghts. So Keras is probably ignoring them for saving. I believe you must use `self.add_weight`, as described in the documentation: https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/ --- Now, integrating this with the 'alien' Elmo weights might be complex.... must think about it.

Comment: @AadityaUra 2.0.0

Comment: Or, alternatively, you manually save the elmo weights and after loading the model manually load the elmo weights.

Comment: Important check: does the loaded Keras model give satisfactory results?

Comment: @AadityaUra Keras '2.3.1'

Comment: @DanielMöller Yes as I said I am getting almost same accuracy during inference. That's why I am confused.

Comment: @Geeocode I am using Tensorflow 1.14

Comment: @AadityaUra Yes, I thought as I wrote the issues, I make a conda env with that version. Your Keras version?

Comment: I mean the "loaded" model, not the "trained" model. (Load in a completely new environment)

Comment: @DanielMöller I think Keras is not saving the Elmo model, because while inference part I have to provide the Keras model architecture but in Tensorflow I can load the graph directly without providing all the code because it's saving whole model architecture?

Comment: @Geeocode it's '2.2.4'